# Check to see if these directories exist

Tags: python

For this code, i want to be able to confirm these directorys were made, so make it print something like this in the for statement

if

print "these directorys exist"

else

"these directorys do not exist"

```
    import os

    GROUPS_MANAGERS = '/staff/Managers' #Managers directory
    GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE = '/staff/Salesman' #Sales associate directory
    GROUPS_CASHIERS = '/staff/Cashiers' #Cashiers directory
    GROUPS_STOCKERS = '/staff/Stockers' #Stockers directory 

    groups = [GROUPS_MANAGERS, GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE, GROUPS_CASHIERS, GROUPS_STOCKERS]

    for path in (groups):
          os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)    #if directory doesn't exist, make it
```

Comment: just for the lols, here's a one liner `print("these directories exist" if all(map(lambda p: os.path.exists(p) and os.path.isdir(p), groups)) else "these directories do not all exist")`

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap remove the *exist_ok* flag and wrap your code in a try/except clause. In fact, os.makedirs will raise and exception if the directory already exists. Let's see how:

```
import os

GROUPS_MANAGERS = '/staff/Managers'  # Managers directory
GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE = '/staff/Salesman'  # Sales associate directory
GROUPS_CASHIERS = '/staff/Cashiers'  # Cashiers directory
GROUPS_STOCKERS = '/staff/Stockers'  # Stockers directory

groups = [GROUPS_MANAGERS, GROUPS_SALESASSOCIATE,
          GROUPS_CASHIERS, GROUPS_STOCKERS]

for path in (groups):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
        print("these directorys do not exist")
    except:
        print("these directorys exist")
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

If you Want to check one by one:

```
 for dir_path in groups:
     if os.path.exists(dir_path)  :
         print (f"{dir_path} exists") 
     else:
        print (f"{dir_path} doesn't exist")
```

If you Want to check all directories:

```
if all(os.path.exists(dir_path) for dir_path in groups):
    print (" all directories exist")

else:
    print ("these directorys do not exist")
```